# How do I display message in one line of code and close it later in another line in c#?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and using windows forms.

I have `form1` with button to for printing POS receipt, the printing process takes long time (about 3 seconds) to finish so I want to display a message from the moment I click the Print button and close it once the printing is finished .

Example:

```
private void button_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         // show message "Printing Please wait"

         // Printing processing...
         // Printing processing...
         // Printing processing...
         // Printing processing...
         // Printing finished.

         //close the above message 

    }
```

Anyone knows how to do that? Please help , Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MessageBox.Show()` and threads.

```
private void button_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
    t.Start();
    // Printing processing...
    // Printing processing...
    // Printing processing...
    // Printing processing...
    // Printing finished.

    if(t.IsAlive)
    t.Abort();
}


void ThreadProc()
{
MessageBox.Show("Printing... Please Wait...","Printing...");
}
```

Comment: I tried it but the message did not close when the printing is finished . any idea? tnx

Answer (score 1):

If you execute a time-consuming operation, it can cause your user interface to seem it has stopped responding even if it hasn’t.

With the BackgroundWorker class  you can run an operation on a separate, dedicated thread. When you have time-consuming operations you can use the BackgroundWorker class to show a alert form, displaying that your application is in progress.

Create a BackgroundWorker and listen for events that report the progress of your operation and signal when your operation is finished.

A solution is posted by Per Schlüter at [Show progress dialog during long process – C#](http://perschluter.com/show-progress-dialog-during-long-process-c-sharp/) - give it a try for your needs.